# Powershell error during making copy of outlook folder

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

I try to make copy of all folders from user account into pst file. Script works fine for all folders except Inbox. When I try to copy data from inbox at end of copying I have error

> Exception calling "CopyTo" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot move or copy folders. Cannot copy folder. A top-level folder cannot be copied to one of its subfolders. Or, you may not have appropriate permissions for the folder. To check your permissions for the folder, right-click the folder, and then click Properties on the shortcut menu."

Script below

```
$start = Get-Date

#checking if outlook is running
$isRunning = (@(Get-Process -ea silentlycontinue OUTLOOK).count -gt 0)

#showing dialog to choose direcotry where pst should be saved
$app = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, "C:\")
if ($folder.Self.Path -ne "") {
    $path = $folder.Self.Path+"\"+$env:USERNAME+".pst"
} else {
    Write-Host "directory not selected. Exiting.."
    [Environment]::Exit(1)
}

#reference to outlook
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$ns = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#adding personal archive file
$ns.AddStoreEx($path, 1)
Write-Host created $path
$dst = $ns.Folders.GetLast()
Write-Host folder name: $dst.Name

#list of directory types to copy. more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868.aspx
$folderTypes = 9,10,3,16,6,12,4,5,30,13,28

#iterating trough list of directories and for each dir make copy in pst file. next counting of objects in archive and pst
foreach ($id in $folderTypes) { 
    $src = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($id)
    $tmp = $src.copyTo($dst)
    Write-Host copied to $tmp.name 
}

#deattaching personal store from outlook
$ns.GetType().InvokeMember('RemoveStore',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $ns, ($dst))
Write-Host $dst.name closed

#if outlook wasn't running on start we must close it
if (-not $isRunning) {
    Write-Host closing outlook
    $outlook.Quit()
}

$end = Get-Date
$diff = New-TimeSpan -start $start -end $end
Write-Host done
"time elapsed {0:g}" -f $diff
```

Any ideas why this error occurs? 
Thanks in advace

Comment: Have you identified which folder makes problems? Perhaps you can get a clue if you print out the name before the copy operation...

Comment: The error message suggests that you don't have the required permissions. Did you verify that?

Comment: It's Inbox folder. I just checked this manually (in outlook with drag'n'drop) and this error still exists. I doing this as current user, so I should have full permissions to this user Inbox. But to be sure I added this user as owner to this folder. It didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have the DisableCrossAccountCopy key in the windows registry set. Here is what the [CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869482(v=office.15).aspx) method description states:

> Setting the REG_MULTI_SZ value, DisableCrossAccountCopy, in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook in the Windows registry has the side effect of disabling this method.

Also I'd suggest releasing underlying COM objects in the code instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Comment: Checked, I don't have this key in registry. This script will be executed on user machine to make local copy of his data. Maybe this info help somehow. And thanks for the tip about releasing resurces